# Don't understand a step of SIFT algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, sift

I'm trying to implement my own version in MATLAB of the [SIFT](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) algorithm. I know that there are a lot of existing implementations but I would like to develop my own version to better understand the whole process.

At the moment I'm able to find the keypoints in the different scale-space and octaves but I didn't understand how to bring back to the original octaves the keypoints that I found in the other octaves. Is it done with a simple interpolation?

I read the original article of Lowe and also other tutorials but I miss this point. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read [this](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-introduction/).

Comment: Thank you. I have already read that tutorial, but he doesn't explain how to bring back the keypoints to the original octaves or at least I didn't see that point. He explains very well how to find subpixel maxima and minima and hot to get rid of some keypoints.